# Formatting error in Mathematica 12

Tags: kernel-startup

Recently, my copy of Mathematica v.12 started reporting the error

> An improperly formatted directive with head Times was encountered.

on startup.

[image: pop-up error message]
This error also shows up in the Messages window while working with random notebooks.

[image: message box error list]
Does anyone know what the cause of such a message is? I tried to reinstall Mathematica but that didn't help. I work with a version for MacOS v. 10.15.1.

Comment: Do you have any code in this file `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`?

Comment: No, the file contains only a comment "(** User Mathematica initialization file **)"

Comment: It could be some package or palette that you installed. Have you installed any? I suggest you click the `...` button next to the message, choose Show Stack Trace, take a screenshot of that and include it in the question above.

Comment: Error messages only appear in the Message window and there is no ... symbol next to it. They generate every time I switch notebooks or swipe it. I have not installed any extra packages or palletes.

Comment: What does `FileNames["*.*", FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"}], 5]` return?

Comment: It returns this: `{"/Users/bartek/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
SystemResources/FunctionalFrequency/AutocompletionHistory.m", \
"/Users/bartek/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
SystemResources/FunctionalFrequency/CodeAssistHistory10.4.m", \
"/Users/bartek/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
SystemResources/FunctionalFrequency/CodeAssistHistory11.2.m"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the advice of the Wolfram Technical Support I have performed a [clean start of Mathematica.](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) All the preferences and history were removed in the process but the problem was solved.